# Can AWS Eventbridge be used to pass SQS message to other AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, event-bus

I would like to trigger on received SQS message a mechanism where it would pass the content of this message into other AWS services like DynamoDB, Kinesis, SNS.

Can it be done right now? Currently the only event I was able to capture from SQS in EventBridge was on SQS queue attribute change. If it is possible, can I manipulate this message before passing it to other streams?

In case it is not possible what are the alternatives? Lambda function which would trigger on received SQS message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can trigger the lambda function when the new message recived in the SQS. Do processing on the message and then forward it to next service. If you fanout that message to multiple services then you can use SNS or if just want a particular targeted service then you can use Eventbridge too. I hope this helps.